# Download iPhone backups from iCloud

Tags: icloud, icloud-api

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically download iPhone / iPad backups from iCloud?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Fair enough. I would like to write a Quantified Self app that watches my iPhone backup from iCloud to gain insights about how much time I spend on the phone, who I send/receive SMS from, etc.

It is something I have wanted to do for a while, but seeing this (http://www.macrumors.com/2012/05/18/elcomsofts-phone-forensics-software-offers-near-real-time-access-to-icloud-backups/) makes me think it is possible.